# How do I trim a string after certain amount of characters appear more then once in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to scan a string and every time it reads a certain character 3 times, I would like to cut the remaining string

for example: 
The string "C:\Temp\Test\Documents\Test.doc" would turn into "C:\Temp\Test\"

Every time the string hits "\" 3 times it should trim the string

here is my code that I am working on

```
prefix = ["" for x in range(size)]
num = 0
...            
...            
            for char in os.path.realpath(src):
                for x in prefix:
                    x = char
                    if x =='\': # I get an error here
                        num = num + 1
                    if num == 3:
                        break
                    print (num)

            print(prefix)
...
...
```

the `os.path.realpath(src)` is the string with with the filepath. The "prefix" variable is the string array that I want to store the trimmed string.

Please let me know what I need to fix or if there is a simpler way to perform this.

Answer (score 2):

Do `split` and then slice list to grab required and `join`:

```
s = 'C:\Temp\Test\Documents\Test.doc'

print('\\'.join(s.split('\\')[:3]) + '\\')
# C:\Temp\Test\
```

Note that `\` (backslash) is an escaping character. To specifically mean a backslash, force it to be a backslash by adding a backslash before backslash `\\`, thereby removing the special meaning of backslash.

Comment: Thank you so much! One more thing, how would I be able to remove the "C:\" in the same string? Trim everything after the first 3 '\' and trim everything before the first '\'

Comment: `print('\\'.join(s.split('\\')[1:3]) + '\\')`.

Answer (score 1):

In python the backslash character is used as an escape character. If you do \n it does a newline, \t does a tab. There are many other things such as \" lets you do a quote in a string. If you want a regular backslash you should do "\\"

Comment: That fixes one problem that I have. The prefix string is not working. How do I create a character string in python? I also get an error at creating the variable "prefix".

Comment: @Apmartin you are never changing what is inside prefix

Comment: @Apmartin, You do not store anything to `prefix`. `x = char` does not do that. It just assigns to `x` a looping variable and is simply thrown away in the very next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
s = "C:\\Temp\\Test\\Documents\\Test.doc"
answer = '\\'.join(s.split('\\', 3)[:3])
```

Comment: This did not answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do..

```
x = "C:\Temp\Test\Documents\Test.doc"
print('\\'.join(x.split("\\")[:3])+"\\")
```